Why are Oracle and SQL Server producing different sort orders?
I've got a table with a column of BANK_ID alphanumeric (VARCHAR2 in Oracle, VARCHAR in SQL Server) length 12. There are three records with BANK_ID of BARCLAYS, BARCLAYS_LDN and BARC_FRA_EUR.
In Oracle, when I select the records in the table table with ORDER BY BANK_ID, I get
BARCLAYS
BARCLAYS_LDN
BARC_FRA_EUR

which is what I'd expect because the hex value of L (4C) is lower than the hex value of _ (5F). I also get this order when I use the sorting functionality in the 4GL with which I'm accessing the database.
In SQL Server, and in Windows if I create three files with these values as the file names, I get
BARC_FRA_EUR
BARCLAYS
BARCLAYS_LDN

Any idea why this is happening and is there any way to make one of them give the same result as the other, preferably SQL Server to give the Oracle result seeing as the Oracle one looks correct to me?
This needs to be a general solution, not just one for these three values.
I haven't tried anything because I haven't got the slightest idea where to start.

Sounds like you want a binary collation order (although no person would want to), try something like: ORDER BY yourcolumn collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_BIN2

It may not be as simple as a binary sort. You likely need to investigate the character set sorting rules active on your Oracle database (see Linguistic Sorting and String Searching )and then choose the equivalent SQL Server collation (see Collation and Unicode support), or one close enough to serve your needs. For limited cases such as sorting your BANK_ID column, COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN may serve your needs.

I would think that Oracle is using binary codepoints to sort and you find this "looks correct". You can define a specific binary collation in the SQL Server column itself, or during the query in the ORDER BY clause.
Applying the collation to the SQL Server column is simpler to use, if you actually have the privileges to change a column collation:
create table t (
  bank_id varchar(12) collate Latin1_General_BIN2
);

insert into t (bank_id) values ('BARC_FRA_EUR');
insert into t (bank_id) values ('BARCLAYS');
insert into t (bank_id) values ('BARCLAYS_LDN');

select * from t order by bank_id;

Results in:
bank_id
------------
BARCLAYS
BARCLAYS_LDN
BARC_FRA_EUR

See SQL Server Example and Oracle Example.
Alternatively -- if you cannot change the SQL Server table -- you can apply the collation in the ORDER BY clause as in the ORDER BY example:
select * from t order by bank_id collate Latin1_General_BIN2;

You'll need to remember to do this on each and every query, though, to get consistent results.
